# Drag elements simultaneously in a uniform circular motion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to achieve simultaneously move with mouse drag of multiple divs in a uniform circular motion.

Please review my fiddle. The issue is when I drag Div number "3" or "1" it always focus on the div "2". Also, the time of rotation of the divs using "transform" the position of the mouse cursor and the divs are mismatched.

**HTML**

```
<div class="a" id="d">
  <div class="sm-1">1</div>
  <div class="sm-2">2</div>
  <div class="sm-3">3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.a {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative
}

.sm-1,
.sm-2,
.sm-3 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.sm-1 {
  top: 70%;
  background: red;
}

.sm-2 {
  top: 50%;
  right: -33px;
  background: green;
}

.sm-3 {
  top: -33px;
  right: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function rotateOnMouse(e, pw, elm) {
    var offset = pw.offset();
    var center_x = (offset.left) + ($(pw).width() / 2);
    var center_y = (offset.top) + ($(pw).height() / 2);
    var mouse_x = e.pageX;
    var mouse_y = e.pageY;
    var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
    var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 100;

    $(pw).css({
      '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
      '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
      '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
    });

    $(elm).css({
      '-moz-transform': 'rotate(-' + degree + 'deg)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(-' + degree + 'deg)',
      '-o-transform': 'rotate(-' + degree + 'deg)',
      '-ms-transform': 'rotate(-' + degree + 'deg)'
    });
  }

  $('.a').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;

    document.onmousemove = function(e2) {
      rotateOnMouse(e2, $('.a'), $('div[class^=sm-]'));
    };
  });

  function closeDragElement() {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1h3ps54c/

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend that you use `canvas` since the calculations outside it are more 
 complex.

However I provide the solutuion here without a canvas: https://jsfiddle.net/mxgec1n7/

-1. using `offsetWidth/offsetHeight` on dom element instead of `$.offset()`, solves the problem with flickering

-2. To correctly calculate rotation you need to remember the last degrees of rotation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lastDegree=0 //degree when mousedown ended
  var currentDegree=0  //current degree as mouse moves
  var aElem=$(".a")[0]; //element
  var startDragDegree; //degree when mousedown started


  function findCenter(elem){//find center of element
    var x = (elem.offsetLeft) + (elem.offsetWidth / 2);
    var y = (elem.offsetTop) + (elem.offsetHeight / 2);
    return {x,y}
  }

  function rotateOnMouse(e, pw) {
    var center = findCenter(pw[0])
    var mouse = {x: e.pageX, y:e.pageY};
    var radians = Math.atan2(mouse.x - center.x, mouse.y - center.y);
    var currentMouseDegree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1);
    currentDegree = (currentMouseDegree-startDragDegree)+lastDegree;
    $(pw).css({
      '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + currentDegree + 'deg)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + currentDegree + 'deg)',
      '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + currentDegree + 'deg)',
      '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + currentDegree + 'deg)'
    });
  }

  $('.a').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var mouseInitial = {x: e.pageX, y:e.pageY};    
    var center = findCenter($(".a")[0])
    var radians = Math.atan2(mouseInitial.x - center.x, mouseInitial.y - center.y);
    startDragDegree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1);

    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = function(e2) {
      rotateOnMouse(e2, $('.a'));
    };
  });

  function closeDragElement() {
    lastDegree = currentDegree;
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
});
```

You could also use an out-of-the-box solution like this: https://github.com/PixelsCommander/Propeller

Comment: Yes. You are right about the Canvas. It is pretty easier to calculate the same inside the Canvas. By the way, it works perfectly. Thank you for your kind support.